# Nested LinearLayouts and center aligning them

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I've been trying to achieve this using nested LinearLayouts. Tried setting both  width and height to 0dp . But it's not achieving 80% width and height.  But it's working when i'm switching it to just single dimension ( ie, *just* width or height ).  Couldn't get any info on it though i googled a lot .

*So, now the question* :  does the Layout Weight work with both dimensions together?.

Note:  I cannot use center gravity it , due to the lack of proper width in the children. They need to get it from linearlayout2 ( fill_parent ) .

[image: layout figure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1、The LinearLayout weight do not work both with width and height, It depends on the orientation of it. the default is Horizontal.

Comment: Damn. Didn't figure that out till now though i used to change to vertical wherever i wanted  to use weight on height , Guess it was  involuntary!. Except on this occasion, which got me confused. Thanks.